# Entity Framework code-first, Many-to-Many relationship on the same table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity, code-first

I'm building a social network with Friend function.
My idea is that I've already had the default ApplicationUser class, so I create a new table called **Friend**

```
public class Friend
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string SenderId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }

    //Status == true : Friend request accepted
    //Status == false : Friend request not accepted
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

In the **ApplicationUser**, I define 2 navigation properties *Senders* and *Receivers* (to link to Friend table)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Gender { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Job { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Senders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Receivers { get; set; }
}
```

And finally in ApplicationDbContext, I declare relationships between 2 tables using Fluent Api

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public DbSet<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Senders)
            .WithMany(a => a.Receivers)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("ReceiverId");
                m.MapRightKey("SenderId");
                m.ToTable("Friends");
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

But when I add-migration, it creates 2 tables like this, and neither of them is what I need (one doesn't have foreign keys, one doesn't have Status properties)

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Friends1",
            c => new
                {
                    SenderId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ReceiverId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Status = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.SenderId, t.ReceiverId });

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Friends",
            c => new
                {
                    SenderId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ReceiverId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.SenderId, t.ReceiverId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.SenderId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ReceiverId)
            .Index(t => t.SenderId)
            .Index(t => t.ReceiverId);

    }
```

What am I supposed to do :( I've searched on internet and this seems legit but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I add-migration, it creates 2 tables like this, and neither of them is what I need (one doesn't have foreign keys, one doesn't have Status properties)

This is because you mixed the two possible `many-to-many` associations supported by EF - one using implicit junction table (from the Fluent API configuration) and the other using explicit junction table (`Friend` entity) and two `one-to-many` associations.

Since the first approach can be used only if you don't have additional data associated with the association, and you have one (`Status` property), you need to use the second approach.

In order to do that, change the type of the navigation properties as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<Friend> Senders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Friend> Receivers { get; set; }
}
```

and the configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Senders)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReceiverId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Receivers)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.SenderId);
```

Comment: One more question, how can I retrieve List of friends of one User?

Comment: I need a list of ApplicationUser which are friends to another ApplicationUser. So I pass in its ID and query as following

Comment: var friends = (from f in _context.Friends 
                           from u in _context.Users
                           where f.ReceiverId == u.Id || f.SenderId == u.Id
                           where u.Id==id
                           where f.Status==true
                           select new
                           {
                               Id=u.Id,
                               Name=u.Name,
                           }
                ).ToList();

Comment: `var friends = (from u in _context.Users
         where u.Id == id
         from fId in (from s in u.Senders where s.Status == true select s.SenderId)
          .Concat(from r in u.Receivers where r.Status == true select r.ReceiverId)
         join f in _context.Users on fId equals f.Id
         select new { Id = f.Id, Name = f.Name, })
       .ToList();`

Comment: thanks, but seems like the query actually get the user its self rather than its friends

Comment: Basically the idea is to collect ReceiverIds where SenderId is our user, plus SenderIds where ReceiverId is our user. Then join these Ids with Users table to get the actual friends.

Comment: So w/o using navigation properties it should be something like this:    `var friends =
    (from fid in
     (from f in _context.Friends where f.SenderId == id && f.Status == true select f.ReceiverId)
     .Concat
     (from f in _context.Friends where f.ReceiverId == id && f.Status == true select f.SenderId)
     join u in _context.Users on fid equals u.Id
     select new { u.Id, u.Name }).ToList();`

Comment: or this:    `var friends =
    (from f in _context.Friends
     where (f.SenderId == id || f.ReceiverId == id) && f.Status == true
     join u in _context.Users
     on f.SenderId == id ? f.ReceiverId : f.SenderId equals u.Id
     select new { u.Id, u.Name }).ToList();`